# Twitter4j Unhandled Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter

Twitter.getHomeTimeline() returns a List of latest tweets from user's home timeline. Unfortunately. Eclipse is telling me I have an unhanded exception. When I looked up the method, getHomeTimeline() advised me that the exception is thrown when the twitter network is unavailable. How could this be? I am very new to this twitter4j API and do not understand how the network can not be reached at this time.

```
package com.follow3d.rob;
import java.util.List;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.*;
public class Follow3d {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXX")//removed on purpose
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXXXX")//removed on purpose
      .setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXXXXXXX")//removed on purpose
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("  XXXXXXXXXX");//removed on purpose
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
    for (Status status1 : statuses ){
        System.out.println(status1.getUser().getName() + ": " + status1.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

> Throws:
>   TwitterException - when Twitter service or network is unavailable

Comment: Disconnect your computer from the internet.  The Twitter service or network is now unavailable to you.

Comment: @Aurand Well, yeah.. But the problem is, my computer is not disconnected to the internet, and I am still getting this error when I run this program.

Comment: The error you get is from **the compiler**. You're not getting any exception from Twitter4J. You're getting an error from the compiler telling you that your code **must** handle the declared thrown exception (i.e. catch it, or rethrow it). Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you. @JB Nizet

Answer (score 0):

Ta Da!!!! It works!!! Thank you for the help guys. I just needed to handle the exception.

```
package com.follow3d.rob;

import java.util.List;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.*;

public class Follow3d {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxx")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxx")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxxxxxx")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxxxxxxx");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    try {
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
        for (Status status1 : statuses) {
            System.out.println(status1.getUser().getName() + ": " + status1.getText());
        }
    } catch (TwitterException name) {
        System.out.println("You don't have internet connection.");
    }

    finally {
        System.out.println("You don't have internet connection.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `"You don't have internet connection"` in finally? Why?

Comment: Yeah, you know, I don't actually need to include the finally statement.  But I was learning how to catch exceptions and I thought it was required. It's okay though, it doesn't hurt anything I don't think

Comment: Ok, but fyi `finally` always runs. So if your `try` finishes succesfully, you will still see "no internet" in your log, which might be confusing. You usually use finally to clean up your resources (close streams, database connections, etc...)

Comment: Thank you, I have changed this in my code. Your explanation has been helpful to me.